# AWS Elastic IP not in subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

So I have a domain on AWS and an EC2 instance. I am trying to add an elastic IP to the EC2 instance but when I try to do that it says 'IP address not in subnet' What does this mean and how do I fix it? I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by having "a domain on AWS". So, you've allocated an EIP, presumably scoped to VPC. Then you've tried to associate that EIP to an EC2 instance (in a VPC) or to an ENI (attached to an EC2 instance in a VPC) and it failed. Are you using the console or CLI? Is "IP address not in subnet" the exact message that you see?

Answer (score 0):

An Elastic IP address maps a Public IP address to a Private IP address.

When associating an Elastic IP, you must supply *either*:

- An Instance ID, or
- A Network Interface ID, or
- A Private IP address

Your `IP address not in subnet` error *suggests* that it is trying to associated a Public IP address with a Private IP address that is not in a subnet.

If your instance has only one network interface, it is easiest to specify the Instance ID.